# VBA Tools>References Prompting for ProjectPassword to Open

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I have searched online for a bit with no luck in finding a way around this.

I inherited an Excel workbook where the VBA code **not protected**. I can view | edit the code with no problem. However, when trying to run the code I get:

> Compile Error: Can't find project or library.

I then go to `Tools > References` in the VBE and am prompted for a `VBAProject Password`.

My experience tells me that there is a reference set to some other VBAProject that is password protected that is no longer relevant, or at least it's missing, but how can I bypass this password error to check on the missing project.

Comment: Have you tried querying the `wkbk.VBProject.References`?

Comment: there's a `FullPath` and `IsBroken` property of each reference, those might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens. It's been a while. I forgot about that. Huge help in right direction, but unfortunately, it still errors out when I try to remove the broken reference with VBA or gather any information except the `GUID`. Piggy-backed [this code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=272) to help with removal.

Comment: One idea would be to export all of the modules, import in to a new Workbook, and then add the non-problematic references only.

Comment: @DavidZemens I've tested all the references in the Citrix environment where the tool is normally run. I discovered that the offending reference is with Adobe Acrobat. I have Reader on my desktop machine and there is one reference that is not translating from Acrobat to Reader. So, the easy answer is I need to do my playing in the Citrix environment! (Guess I can really delete the question, as the answer doesn't seem that universally helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the end result answer may not be that universally helpful, I thought the methodology I used to get the answer may be useful for others.

I discovered the offending reference was

```
Name: ACRODISTXLib
FullPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\acrodist.exe
```

The citrix path where the file is normally run houses Adobe Acrobat. My desktop houses Adobe Reader.

Adobe Acrobat has 2 other references:

```
Name: Acrobat
FullPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\acrobat.tlb
Name: AcrobatAccessLib 
FullPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\plug_ins\Accessibility.api
```

These get translated nicely to machines with only Reader installed as:

```
Name: Acrobat
FullPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.dll
Name: AcrobatAccessLib
FullPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\plug_ins\Accessibility.api
```

The first reference does not.

This is the code I used to compare the references in each workbook in each environment, which I decided to it when I get an error in accessing the reference name and fullpath in the workbook on my desktop:

```
Dim ref As Object

For Each ref In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    Debug.Print ref.Name & " | " & ref.fullpath
    'If ref.isbroken Then
        'ref.Remove
        'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove ref
    'End If
Next
```